# selectively delete lines

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file with tab delimited data spread across 16 columns.
I want to delete the complete row where the values 1260, 1068 and 907 found in 6th column.

```
9513    2010-06-15 17:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-15 18:00:02 \N
9523    2010-06-15 18:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-15 19:00:02 \N
9534    2010-06-15 19:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-15 20:00:02 \N
9543    2010-06-15 20:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-15 21:00:02 \N
9552    2010-06-15 21:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-15 22:00:02 \N
9560    2010-06-15 22:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-15 23:00:02 \N
9569    2010-06-15 23:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-16 00:00:02 \N
9579    2010-06-16 00:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-16 01:00:02 \N
9589    2010-06-16 01:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-16 02:00:01 \N
9599    2010-06-16 02:00:00 94  0   69  12  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2010-06-16 03:00:02 \N
95642733    2011-10-19 19:00:00 4341    0   1263    0   11  0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2011-10-19 20:05:06 \N
95642732    2011-10-19 19:00:00 4341    0   1260    0   24635   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2011-10-19 20:05:06 \N
95642540    2011-10-19 19:00:00 4050    0   1068    103 113 2   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2011-10-19 20:05:06 \N
95642539    2011-10-19 19:00:00 4050    0   907 19  0   0   0   0.0000  0   \N  \N  \N  2011-10-19 20:05:06 \N
```

Comment: If this is not something recurring, why  not just load the data into the text editor and delete the lines you don't want. (How big is the data, and do the rows with these values have to be deleted on an ongoing basis in numerous files?)

Comment: Will there by any space characters in the file at all, or can we just consider "whitespace" to be your field separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk is the tool you want to use.

```
awk '$6==1260 || $6==1068 || $6==907 {next} {print}'
```

**What does this do?**

Awk runs a block of code on each line of your file.  The code starts with an expression that must evaluate true (in this case the three possible values of the 6th field), followed by commands in curly braces.  In this case, the command `next` tells it to proceed to the next input line without running any more commands.

If the three comparisons FAIL, and we don't run the `next`, then we print the line.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to us is [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).  Awk is an amazingly powerful language inside UNIX, and if you ever run into a complicated test-streaming problem, awk is your solution.

Try this script:

```
awk '{
if ($6 != 1260 || $6 != 1068 || $6 != 907)
   print $0;
}' file.txt >> output_file.txt
```

Comment: He didn't want to eliminate the 6th column, he wanted to eliminate the row.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot half way through writing the script. It's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed?):

```
sed '/^\(\S*\s*\)\{5\}\(1260\|1068\|907\)\s/d' file
```

or generally:

```
sed '/^\([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*\)\{5\}\(1260\|1068\|907\)[[:space:]]/!d'
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `{n}` notation is only ERE, so this could be done with `sed -r` in Linux (adjusting the backslashes), but not much else.  Might work in FreeBSD if you switch to full character class names or just put tabs right into the regex.

Comment: @ghoti I think `\{m,n\}` is POSIX BRE see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/syntax/posix_basic_regular_expression)

Comment: Ah, right you are.  Just the `\S` and `\s` that would cause problems, then.

Comment: @ghoti you may be right but if I run the same solution using the `--posix` switch I get the same result.

Comment: That's still YOUR implementation of sed.  FreeBSD's sed *does not* understand `\s` or `\S` no matter what your version does with the `--posix` option.

Comment: @ghoti included a solution with character class names

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '$6!=1260 && $6!=1068 && $6!=907' file
```

Comment: No need for regular expressions when string equality will do. Plus this answer will also delete lines containing 9070, for example.